# First time Deploying Qt Application, dynamically link?

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, dynamic-linking

I'm starting to look into deploying a Qt application I've been developing but I've never had to deploy any C++ application before this.

I want to be able to ship my product as a pre-compiled executable that dynamically links against shared library files(Qt) for Linux/Windows so that there is an executable that looks in its own sub directories for libraries instead of libraries that may be installed as a result of other Qt products.

Is this something that is possible? Or must the Qt library files be installed separately for an application to link against them? I want to avoid requiring the end user to install ANYTHING on their systems while also avoiding static linking.

Answer (score 3):

This is a normal behavior for Qt.  How to do it greatly depends on your build system.

If you use CMake, you can generate installers with CPack.  Here is a [link](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-September/024003.html) to adding the required shared libraries to an installer.  CPack makes many different types of installers for Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X.

You can also generate your own installers using NSIS.  This is a lot more involved but doable.

Qt has [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment.html) on how to deploy applications that use their libraries.

At my company, we do both CPack and NSIS.  The CPack way is a lot easier and there is more examples online.

Comment: But I don't want to install, the application needs to be usable by people who don't have administrative rights.

I want the benefits of a static linked application, but without static linking(licensing issues).

Comment: Even in that case, all you are doing is providing the files like an installer does, but not placing them in a restricted location.  For example, you can have an installer on Windows request user rights and place the files on the desktop.  As long as you don't do things that require privileged access (i.e. writing to the registry).

Comment: I'm not understanding your point? Why would I need an installer to install to a Desktop then?

Comment: All I am trying to say is that the files you need to provide would be the same as making an installer.  If you make an GUI application with Qt, then you would need to provide the QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll on Windows.  This is the information that is provided with making an installer.  You can just as easily make a folder with all of these files and distribute the folder that way.  Making an installer is more of an automated way of doing the same thing.

Comment: An installer is not needed even if using CPack. It can generate tarballs and other packages as well. look at CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ" for example.